# How do I refactor this code to make it shorter?

Tags: python-3.x, reduction

```
import math
def roundup(x):
return int(math.ceil(x / 10.0)) * 10
w=0
while w == 5:
print("Would you like to *work out* a missing letter in a GTIN-8 code, or *check* a code?")
response = input(":")
if response == 'work out':
    print("Input a 7 digit GTIN-8 code and I'll work out the 8th")
    c1 = int(input("Enter FIRST number: "))
    c2 = int(input("Enter SECOND number: "))
    c3 = int(input("Enter THIRD number: "))
    c4 = int(input("Enter FOURTH number: "))
    c5 = int(input("Enter FIFTH number: "))
    c6 = int(input("Enter SIXTH number: "))
    c7 = int(input("Enter SEVENTH number: "))

    y = (c1*3+c2+c3*3+c4+c5*3+c6+c7*3)
    ru2=roundup(y)
    GTIN8 = ru2-y
    print("Your GTIN8 Code would be: "+str(c1)+str(c2)+str(c3)+str(c4)+str(c5)+str(c6)+str(c7)+str(GTIN8))
    print("Wanna work out another?") 
if response == 'check':
    print("Input a 8 digit GTIN-8 code and I'll check if it's correct")
c1 = int(input("Enter FIRST number: "))
c2 = int(input("Enter SECOND number: "))
c3 = int(input("Enter THIRD number: "))
c4 = int(input("Enter FOURTH number: "))
c5 = int(input("Enter FIFTH number: "))
c6 = int(input("Enter SIXTH number: "))
c7 = int(input("Enter SEVENTH number: "))
c8 = int(input("Enter EIGTH number: "))
y = (c1*3+c2+c3*3+c4+c5*3+c6+c7*3)
ru2=roundup(y)
GTIN8 = ru2-y
if GTIN8 != c8:
    print("Nope that product code is incorrect!")
    reply=input("Want to know the correct answer to your code? Type yes if so: ")
if reply == 'yes':
    print("The correct answer would have been: "+str(GTIN8))
if GTIN8 == c8:
    print("That code is correct!")
```

The problem is that I have tried time and time again, to make this code smaller.

Even by inputting 'response' as a string, to allow the user to type the code in one go.

If you couldn't already tell, this is a code for a GTIN-8 product code and I know there are various other GTIN-8 codes out there but I just couldn't do it, let alone copy.

Comment: Functioning code that you want improved can be submitted to the code review stackexchange

Comment: make a function for inputting your 7 numbers, then reuse that function for both cases. for the one that would need an 8th input, either keep the line you have now, or have your function take in a bool that signifies whether it needs to ask for the 8. you can then return a list with all your values.

Comment: I suggest you ask on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

To get you started, here is one simple way of reducing the number of lines

```
c = [int(x) for x in input("Input a 8 digit GTIN-8 code and I'll check if it's correct").split("")]
```

Now you can access each character with `c[n]`.